# s:WindowedApplication - How to remove system chrome?

Tags: windows, apache-flex, air, flex-spark

I have a Spark `WindowedApplication` (AIR for Windows Desktop) and I want remove the title bar and borders, this option will be set via cmd line when the application is launched.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do a Google search for creating custom window chrome w/ Adobe AIR. I'm not sure if this is something that can be done at runtime; or if it must be a compile time option

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I think it requires a flag in the AIR descriptor file, which is needed at compile time.

Comment: @RIAstar yes, all my searches on google said the same, compile time only. Maybe I'll have to wrap it in dot net or something, or dll calls.

Answer (score 2):

You need to made two changes in the "YouApplicationName_app.xml" by setting "systemChrome" and "transparent" properties.

```
<initialWindow>
    <systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
<initialWindow>
```

And inside your WindowedApplication you have to set these four properties:

```
backgroundAlpha="0"
showTitleBar="false"
borderStyle="none"
showStatusBar="false"
```

You can find more information about that on this links:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS2d929364fa0b81374fa5df4f129dca62884-8000.html
- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=WorkingWithWindows_2.html

Comment: Thanks, but this is for compile time only. I need to set at runtime via the cmd line